# screen coordinates to sharpdx device context coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx

I am new to the sharpdx.

My current work flow is user can capture a pictures using webcam or any cam devices.now i am working to the new feature for users. user able to draw anything at top the image like **(mspaint drawing)**..

So i desired to take xy points in mouse move event ...and its worked perfectly

This Is My Designer code:-

```
<Page x:Class="TEST.GraphicsPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:TEST.Model.Enum;assembly=TEST.Core"
      xmlns:common="clr-namespace:TEST.Core.Common;assembly=TEST.Core"
      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TEST.View.Controls"
      xmlns:metro="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium"
      xmlns:params="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium/params"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      DataContext="{Binding Graphics, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="800"
    Title="GraphicsPage" Loaded="GraphicsPage_OnLoaded" Unloaded="GraphicsPage_OnUnloaded" MouseLeftButtonDown="Page_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Page_MouseLeftButtonUp" PreviewMouseMove="Page_PreviewMouseMove">

    <Grid x:Name="GrdPage" PreviewMouseDown="GrdPage_OnPreviewMouseDown" PreviewMouseWheel="GrdPage_OnPreviewMouseWheel"
          PreviewMouseMove="GrdPage_OnPreviewMouseMove" PreviewTouchDown="GrdPage_OnPreviewTouchDown">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImage,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="spRetake" Margin="0,13,0,0">
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource BackButtonStyle}"  Click="ButtonTrigger" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:ButtonTriggerType.GoBack}" Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Retake" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,3" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="GrdGraphics" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="grdImage" Grid.Column="0" Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,20,10,10">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">

          ///Image is render to this control  
                    <Image x:Name="ImgPhoto" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="1000" MaxWidth="1400" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImgPhoto_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="ImgPhoto_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="ImgPhoto_MouseMove" LostMouseCapture="ImgPhoto_LostMouseCapture" />
///image control
                </Grid>
                <common:ProgressRing x:Name="PrLoading" Margin="100" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsActive="True" Foreground="{StaticResource VioletBrush}" Visibility="{Binding IsProgressVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="#99000000" Width="350"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid x:Name="GrdBorders" Margin="0,1,5,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=RbBorders, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="GrdBorderTitle" Margin="5,0,0,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource GreenBrushTransparent}" Width="50" Height="45"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Path Data="M0,9.6240009L6.6444809,9.6240009 6.6444809,13.513288 3.8906012,13.513288 3.8906012,52.242962 50.401927,52.242962 50.401927,49.327709 54.29,49.327709 54.29,56.134999 0,56.134999z M13.596372,3.8918467L13.596372,42.622032 60.1081,42.622032 60.1081,3.8918467z M9.7070002,0L64.000003,0 64.000003,46.509999 9.7070002,46.509999z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="28" Height="28" Margin="5,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Background="{StaticResource GreenBrushTransparent}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Borders" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <ListView x:Name="LstBorders" Background="Transparent" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
                                  SelectionChanged="LstBorders_SelectionChanged" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GrapicsBorders}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GraphicsBorderListViewItemStyle}" Style="{StaticResource BackgroundGalleryListViewStyle}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid  Grid.Column="0" x:Name="GrdEffects" Margin="5,1,5,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=RbFilters, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="GrdEffectsTitle" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource GreenBrushTransparent}" Width="50" Height="45" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" Data="M44.02605,20.846C44.02605,20.846 63.682006,24.103257 63.682006,38.870418 63.682006,42.772187 63.682006,49.664208 63.682006,53.565377 63.682006,66.221799 51.658645,58.015256 51.658645,50.555524 51.658645,40.738351 60.340182,37.173087 56.365394,33.199718z M25.529025,0C34.740886,0,39.964213,12.976948,40.281676,22.477042L40.293128,23.153271 40.635634,23.496004C44.15071,27.013427 48.794879,31.660645 50.360019,33.226604 52.995978,35.863305 51.193019,38.789006 50.089023,39.892009 48.98503,40.995406 28.241208,61.738416 28.241208,61.738416 25.936236,64.043717 17.883273,59.726617 10.261396,52.099114 2.63244,44.474008 -1.684536,36.421304 0.6204343,34.116004L22.599233,12.137394C22.599233,12.137394 24.072108,10.731551 26.071624,10.752226 27.118989,10.763056 28.310851,11.165289 29.511216,12.365994L31.998191,14.858796C33.357127,19.144596 32.48714,22.803398 31.852197,24.675799 30.646153,25.4376 29.839215,26.7741 29.839215,28.308002 29.839215,30.683002 31.76516,32.610805 34.144168,32.610805 36.52415,32.610805 38.450095,30.683002 38.450095,28.308002 38.450095,26.808 37.681121,25.490899 36.519145,24.7214 36.644145,23.702499 36.722144,21.654397 36.354106,19.211597 36.354106,19.211597 36.823226,19.681035 37.592975,20.451304L37.670257,20.528639 37.615382,20.036525C36.595061,11.949274 32.102916,2.4615231 25.529025,2.4615231 17.491012,2.4615231 15.683008,10.664832 15.683008,13.53907L13.222004,13.53907C13.222004,8.3047702,16.56301,0,25.529025,0z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="27" Height="27" Margin="5,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Background="{StaticResource GreenBrushTransparent}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Filters" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <ListView x:Name="LstAdvancedEffect" Width="245" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdvancedEffect}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GraphicsEffectsListViewItemStyle}" Style="{StaticResource BackgroundGalleryListViewStyle}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="GrdEdit" Margin="5,1,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=RbEdit, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="GrdEditTitle"  Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel  Background="{StaticResource GreenBrushTransparent}" Width="50" Height="45" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Path Data="M28.359835,24.709L34.154998,30.052877 27.489999,31.461998z M21.8047,9.3869993L35.634799,9.3869993 30.5925,14.785472 22.157498,14.785472 21.7942,26.555977C21.7942,26.555977,21.324199,34.340181,12.747299,33.399679L5.3957494,33.19948 5.3957494,66.641893C5.395749,67.386995,6.0026888,67.990496,6.7473091,67.990496L44.531299,67.990496C45.273398,67.990496,45.880099,67.386995,45.880099,66.641893L45.880099,26.531576 51.279998,21.086176 51.279998,66.641893C51.279998,70.368498,48.2578,73.386999,44.531299,73.386999L6.7473091,73.386999C3.020749,73.386999,-1.0840647E-06,70.368498,3.4106051E-13,66.641893L3.4106051E-13,32.391882 2.6718787,29.574478 2.674559,29.49638 16.676999,14.785472 16.637898,14.785472 12.894499,18.732675 16.816399,14.579372 16.872298,14.579372 16.996098,14.449471 17.007798,14.449471z M43.024932,5.7089984L52.443,14.399388 40.817794,27.000999 40.619792,25.005898 37.516936,23.951198 37.429824,21.838896 34.333331,21.018594 33.961013,18.635792 31.396998,18.307692z M49.488421,0.0016288757C49.906531,0.018204689,50.296157,0.1614809,50.599376,0.4401598L57.271087,6.5981958C58.080863,7.3442647,57.976867,8.7787952,57.033995,9.7973371L55.755431,11.184999 46.149001,2.3229232 47.428763,0.93428135C48.01562,0.298316,48.791575,-0.026000023,49.488421,0.0016288757z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="28" Height="28" Margin="5,0,5,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Background="{StaticResource GreenBrushTransparent}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Basic Edit" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="Brightness" FontSize="18" Foreground="#929292" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                                <Slider x:Name="Brightness" params:Slider.ThumbThickness="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="Contrast" FontSize="18" Foreground="#929292" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                                <Slider x:Name="Contrast" params:Slider.ThumbThickness="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="Saturation" FontSize="18" Foreground="#929292" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                                <Slider x:Name="Saturation" params:Slider.ThumbThickness="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="Temp" FontSize="18" Foreground="#929292" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                                <Slider x:Name="Temp" params:Slider.ThumbThickness="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="Tint" FontSize="18" Foreground="#929292" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                                <Slider x:Name="Tint" params:Slider.ThumbThickness="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="Sharpen / Blur" FontSize="18" Foreground="#929292" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                                <Slider x:Name="Blur" params:Slider.ThumbThickness="9" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,0,5"  Minimum="-100" Maximum="100" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Light" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                        <RadioButton x:Name="RbFilters" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="55" IsChecked="{Binding IsFilterChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource EffectsRadioButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding IsFilter,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" Data="M44.02605,20.846C44.02605,20.846 63.682006,24.103257 63.682006,38.870418 63.682006,42.772187 63.682006,49.664208 63.682006,53.565377 63.682006,66.221799 51.658645,58.015256 51.658645,50.555524 51.658645,40.738351 60.340182,37.173087 56.365394,33.199718z M25.529025,0C34.740886,0,39.964213,12.976948,40.281676,22.477042L40.293128,23.153271 40.635634,23.496004C44.15071,27.013427 48.794879,31.660645 50.360019,33.226604 52.995978,35.863305 51.193019,38.789006 50.089023,39.892009 48.98503,40.995406 28.241208,61.738416 28.241208,61.738416 25.936236,64.043717 17.883273,59.726617 10.261396,52.099114 2.63244,44.474008 -1.684536,36.421304 0.6204343,34.116004L22.599233,12.137394C22.599233,12.137394 24.072108,10.731551 26.071624,10.752226 27.118989,10.763056 28.310851,11.165289 29.511216,12.365994L31.998191,14.858796C33.357127,19.144596 32.48714,22.803398 31.852197,24.675799 30.646153,25.4376 29.839215,26.7741 29.839215,28.308002 29.839215,30.683002 31.76516,32.610805 34.144168,32.610805 36.52415,32.610805 38.450095,30.683002 38.450095,28.308002 38.450095,26.808 37.681121,25.490899 36.519145,24.7214 36.644145,23.702499 36.722144,21.654397 36.354106,19.211597 36.354106,19.211597 36.823226,19.681035 37.592975,20.451304L37.670257,20.528639 37.615382,20.036525C36.595061,11.949274 32.102916,2.4615231 25.529025,2.4615231 17.491012,2.4615231 15.683008,10.664832 15.683008,13.53907L13.222004,13.53907C13.222004,8.3047702,16.56301,0,25.529025,0z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="27" Height="27" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Filters" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="RbBorders" Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="60" Height="55" IsChecked="{Binding IsBorderChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource EffectsRadioButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding IsBorder,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Path Data="M0,9.6240009L6.6444809,9.6240009 6.6444809,13.513288 3.8906012,13.513288 3.8906012,52.242962 50.401927,52.242962 50.401927,49.327709 54.29,49.327709 54.29,56.134999 0,56.134999z M13.596372,3.8918467L13.596372,42.622032 60.1081,42.622032 60.1081,3.8918467z M9.7070002,0L64.000003,0 64.000003,46.509999 9.7070002,46.509999z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="28" Height="28" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Borders" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="RbEdit" Height="55" Margin="0,0,0,10" IsChecked="{Binding IsEditChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource EffectsRadioButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding IsEdit,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Path Data="M28.359835,24.709L34.154998,30.052877 27.489999,31.461998z M21.8047,9.3869993L35.634799,9.3869993 30.5925,14.785472 22.157498,14.785472 21.7942,26.555977C21.7942,26.555977,21.324199,34.340181,12.747299,33.399679L5.3957494,33.19948 5.3957494,66.641893C5.395749,67.386995,6.0026888,67.990496,6.7473091,67.990496L44.531299,67.990496C45.273398,67.990496,45.880099,67.386995,45.880099,66.641893L45.880099,26.531576 51.279998,21.086176 51.279998,66.641893C51.279998,70.368498,48.2578,73.386999,44.531299,73.386999L6.7473091,73.386999C3.020749,73.386999,-1.0840647E-06,70.368498,3.4106051E-13,66.641893L3.4106051E-13,32.391882 2.6718787,29.574478 2.674559,29.49638 16.676999,14.785472 16.637898,14.785472 12.894499,18.732675 16.816399,14.579372 16.872298,14.579372 16.996098,14.449471 17.007798,14.449471z M43.024932,5.7089984L52.443,14.399388 40.817794,27.000999 40.619792,25.005898 37.516936,23.951198 37.429824,21.838896 34.333331,21.018594 33.961013,18.635792 31.396998,18.307692z M49.488421,0.0016288757C49.906531,0.018204689,50.296157,0.1614809,50.599376,0.4401598L57.271087,6.5981958C58.080863,7.3442647,57.976867,8.7787952,57.033995,9.7973371L55.755431,11.184999 46.149001,2.3229232 47.428763,0.93428135C48.01562,0.298316,48.791575,-0.026000023,49.488421,0.0016288757z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="28" Height="28" Margin="0,0,5,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Edit" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource GreenBrush}" BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#4C000000" Height="75">
            <Button Height="40" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,10,0" Content="Next" Style="{DynamicResource NextButtonStyle}"  Click="ButtonTrigger" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:ButtonTriggerType.Next}" />
        </Border>
        <MediaElement Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="MdeBackgroundMusic" Source="{Binding BackgroundMusic}"  Visibility="Collapsed" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="MdeBackgroundMusic_OnMediaEnded" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Codebehind**

```
//List for added points
public List<Point> DrawPoint = new List<Point>();
```

and my mouse move event like this

```
private void Page_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
 if (draw)
    {
     if (DrawPoint .Count > 0)
      {
         var exist = DrawPoint .Any(i => i == e.Getpostion(null));
       if (!exist)
          {

              DrawPoint .Add(e.Getpostion(null));
          }
         else
        {
         DrawPoints.Add(e.Getpostion(null));
         }

        }
    }
}
```

at that time i was draw the points to the render method like this

```
if (_point != null){
SolidColorBrush aBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_d2DContext, SharpDX.Color.Red);

  //looped every added point in user
  foreach (var point in _point)
   {

     _d2DContext.FillEllipse(new Ellipse(new Vector2((float)point.X, (float)point.Y), 10, 10), aBrush);

    }
}
```

but drawed points its wrong what is iam missing. please help me out[image]

**Image Notes**

> Redpoint is now brush the point using above code
>
> X Mark indicates mouse postion on the image.

Comment: It seems like you need to transform your point from screen space to image space. This transformation will probably consist of scaling and translation. Can your image be zoomed? What if the image is larger than the window, can you scroll?

Comment: @Discosultan we did not scroll the image.

Comment: @Discosultan  render device context is fixed.sizes are W:1400 and h:1000

Comment: @Discosultan the original image size is W:640 and H:480 and screen resolution is 1366*768

Comment: we did not zoom the image also.

Comment: Have you tried getting the mouse location relative to the image container, DrawPoint .Add(e.Getpostion(this.ImgPhoto); Also when you draw the red point, are you drawing it relative to the image container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have faced similar  Issue when i working my last project*

> in your Move Event

```
//get current touch point
    var currentPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(this);
   // calculate screen margin for grid image left
     var x = (currentPoint.Bounds.X - (spRetake.ActualWidth + grdImage.Margin.Left)) / grdImage.ActualWidth;
    var y = (currentPoint.Bounds.Y - grdImage.Margin.Top) / grdImage.ActualHeight;

 DrawPoints.Add(new System.Windows.Point(x,y));
```

> And Your Device Class you Need to calculate  rendering device width and height also you should calculate orginal image width and height rendering image actual width

```
// original dimensions
var width = CurrentBitmapSize.Width;
var height = CurrentBitmapSize.Height;

// Find the longest and shortest dimentions
var longestDimension = (width > height) ? width : height;
var shortestDimension = (width < height) ? width : height;

var factor = ((double)longestDimension) / (double)shortestDimension;
// Set width as max
 double newWidth = (float)_d2DContext.PixelSize.Width;
var newHeight = (float)_d2DContext.PixelSize.Width / factor;

//If height is actually greater, then we reset it to use height instead of width
if (width < height)
{
 newWidth = (float)_d2DContext.PixelSize.Height / factor;
  newHeight = (float)_d2DContext.PixelSize.Height;
}

 _drawBrush = new SolidColorBrush(d2DContext, SharpDX.Color.Blue);
 var pWidth = _d2DContext.PixelSize.Width;
 var pHeight = _d2DContext.PixelSize.Height;
int elipseWidth = 10;
 int elipseheight = 15;
foreach (var point in MousePoints.Distinct().ToList())
 {
 var x = (point.X * pWidth) + (elipseWidth / 2);
var y = (point.Y * pHeight) + (elipseheight / 2);

 var ellipseCenter = new Vector2((float)x, (float)y);
 var ellipse = new Ellipse(ellipseCenter, elipseWidth, elipseheight);
//omit if the point not in image container
 if (newWidth >= x && newHeight >= y + 2)
  {
                            d2DContext.FillEllipse(ellipse, _drawBrush);
}
}
```

i think its should worked for you...Any Queries Comment It..